# javascript / jquery memory space between windows / tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I have a page that opens a popup with contents like below:

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script>
    var fileValidationRules = {};
    fileValidationRules.cms_file_input = { exp: "\.(jpg|gif|xls|doc|ppt|pdf|zip)$", desc: "valid download file type", maxKb: 1048576, maxKbDesc: "1 Gb" };
    </script>

    <script src="upload.js?"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form>
            <input type='hidden' id='cms_file_fragment_id' value='303'>

            <button id='cms_file_input_submit_button' type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'> Upload file </button>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

The list of file types and the hidden form field value are different each time the popup is opened, depending in the link clicked.

Suppose the user opens two popups (it seems the browser does not allow that in one tab, but will open two popups from different main window tabs). In *file.js* I'll get use *fileValidationRules* and do:

```
var id = $("#cms_file_fragment_id").val();
```

Question is - do I need to take any precautions to ensure I'm using variable values from the correct window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question is - do I need to take any precautions to ensure I'm using variable values from the correct window?

No. Each window gets its own global environment, which is entirely distinct from other global environments.

If there's a relationship between the windows (parent/child, opener/opened, etc.), it's sometimes possible to access globals of one window in another *explicitly* via (for instance) `parent.nameOfGlobalHere`. But that's explicit, and only works for globals that are properties of the global object. (They all used to be, but as of ES2015, some aren't.)

Comment: Thanks,  that's what I figured would be the case, just checking.